# act_as_list with intermediate table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to use act_as_list to order some items, but I'm having troubles with the scope, I want the scope to be the group of the item, but I have no idea how to do it. This is what I have now:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :types
  has_many :items, through: :types
end

class Type < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
  has_many :items
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :type
  acts_as_list scope: ?
end
```

I tried with scope: [type: :group] but it doesn't work, I tried with:

```
has_one :group, through: :type
```

and

```
def group_id
  type.group.id
end
```

But then I got an error with PG because the column group_id doesn't exists...

Any idea?